# "Неверный пароль" при авторизации

Tags: php

Сделал такую авторизацию. До того зарегистрировал на "сайте" пользователя, его данные сохранились в БД. Логинюсь по е-мэйлу и паролю - вылетает "wrong password",хоть и все правильно.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "include/auth.php",
  data: "email=" + auth_email + "&pass=" + auth_pass + "&rememberme=" + auth_rememberme,
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == 'yes_auth') {
      location.reload();
    } else {
      $("#message-auth").slideDown(400);
      $(".auth-loading").hide();
      $("#button-auth").show();
    }
  }
});
```

```php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  include('db_connect.php');
  include('../functions/functions.php');

  $email = clear_string($_POST["email"]);

  $pass = md5(clear_string($_POST["pass"]));
  $pass = strrev($pass);
  $pass = strtolower("9nm2rv8q".$pass.
    "2yo6z");

  if ($_POST["rememberme"] == "yes") {
    setcookie('rememberme', $email.
      '+'.$pass, time() + 3600 * 24 * 31, "/");
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE email = '$email' AND pass = '$pass'");
  If(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['auth'] = 'yes_auth';
    $_SESSION['auth_pass'] = $row["pass"];
    $_SESSION['auth_email'] = $row["email"];
    $_SESSION['auth_name'] = $row["name"];

    echo 'yes_auth';
  } else {
    echo 'no_auth';
  }
}
```

Comment: Раз "wrong password", значит что-то точно не правильно (: Вы выводили в логи параметры, полученные из `$_POST`? Вы точно хотите соль добавлять **после** того, как применили `md5`? )

Comment: Проверить бы чему равен `$result`

Comment: Без соли тоже не работает.
Я новичок,мне бы подсказать,как проверит чему равен $result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите, что пишу советы в ответ, но мне нужно форматирование и много строк :D

1. Сначала отключите AJAX и настройте форму так, чтобы она слала POST-запрос туда, куда нужно
2. Затем в отредактируйте скрипт авторизации:

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      include('db_connect.php');
      include('../functions/functions.php');

      //Это называется дебаггинг - когда вы выводите всё, что вас интересует, смотрите и анализируете :D. var_dump - очень хорошая для этого функция.
      var_dump($_POST); echo '
'

      $email = clear_string($_POST["email"]);

      //Соль лучше добавлять ДО хеширования, ибо иначе, если кто-то получит доступ к БД - он сразу увидит, что пароль хранится в виде Соль1_хешПароля_Соль2.
      $pass = md5(clear_string($_POST["pass"]));
      $pass = strrev($pass);
      $pass = strtolower("9nm2rv8q".$pass.
        "2yo6z");

      //Имейл и пароль (даже хеш) НЕЛЬЗЯ хранить в печеньках, ибо их стянуть можно без особых проблем. В куки пишут какой-нибудь хеш-id.
      //Иными словами, у вас в таблице пользователей (или в отдельной таблице) должно быть поле, например "session_hash", в который вы при первой авторизации на устройстве с галкой "запомнить меня" записываете какой-нибудь хеш (например, md5($_SESSION['user_id'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
      //и потом настраиваете скрипт на авторизацию либо по логину и паролю, либо по хешу сессии + ещё что-нибудь. Например, связка id+session_hash
      if ($_POST["rememberme"] == "yes") {
        setcookie('rememberme', $email.
          '+'.$pass, time() + 3600 * 24 * 31, "/");
      }

      //Здесь снова дебаг
      var_dump($email, $pass); echo '
';

      //Дальше. Предположим, у вас 1 юзер, и его id - 1.
      //Я не умею в mysqli, поэтому пишу через PDO, вы просто переведёте
      $user = $db->query('SELECT `email`, `pass` FROM `reg_user` WHERE `user_id`=1')->fetch();
      echo '$email == `email`: '; var_dump($email==$user['email']); echo '
';
      echo '$pass == `pass`: '; var_dump($pass==$user['pass']);

      $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE email = '$email' AND pass = '$pass'");
      If(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        //@ - подавление ошибок. А т.к. у нас уже есть вывод до вызова session_start - ошибки точно будут. Поэтому мы их заглушим
        @session_start();
        $_SESSION['auth'] = 'yes_auth';
        $_SESSION['auth_pass'] = $row["pass"];
        $_SESSION['auth_email'] = $row["email"];
        $_SESSION['auth_name'] = $row["name"];

        echo 'yes_auth';
      } else {
        echo 'no_auth';
      }
    }
```

Таким образом вы увидите на экране:

1. Всё, что пришло постом
2. Имейл и пароль после преобразований
3. Равен ли имейл имейлу из БД
4. Равер ли хеш пароля хешу из БД

Читайте, анализируйте, делайте выводы, пишите.

Comment: После var_dump я пишу "echo '< br >';" (без пробелов, разумеется), но стак слишком буквально воспринимает код...

Comment: Спасибо за советы и отзывчивость!Буду сидеть,анализировать.
Только я уже не догоняю " настройте форму так, чтобы она слала POST-запрос туда, куда нужно",а куда нужно то?

Comment: <form method="post" action="/include/auth.php">

Answer (score 0):

Перед `session_start();` напишите `var_dump($row); die();`
и покадите тут результат)
Так же я вам рекомендую не хранить в куке связку email + пароль)

Пустой результат запроса) Смотрите условия, проблема где то там)

Comment: Нет ничего.Если ошибок нет,то и не вышло бы ничего,да?Или это значит,что с переменной что-то нето?